# What can I use to calculate drive times /with/ traffic considered?

Tags: arcpy, google-maps-api, routing, arcgis-online, traffic

I am looking to obtain drive times for a large list of addresses and want the results to take traffic conditions into consideration. For example, drive times from a distribution centre to a store at various times throughout the day.

Google's free API doesn't take traffic into consideration and the business license which does is too costly an option.

Would ArcGIS's API supply this information and would it be easily accessible with ArcPy? I think its World Traffic Service covers drive times has the data I'm looking for.

Are there any other options I may have missed?

Comment: I think you're oversimplifying a very complex problem. How many nodes (distribution centres/stores) do you have in total? Are you trying to develop an origin/destination (O/D) trip table matrix based on time/period of day? Are there any restrictions on how many hours can a driver be on the road? restrictions on worker shifts, time of day, day of the week?

Comment: If you have the traffic data for your area you can use several tools from openstreetmap